# how to show the number of rows in a python code for opening a data file?

Tags: python

I have this code for opening a big file:

```py
fr = open('X1','r')
text = fr.read()
print(text)
fr.close()
```

When I open it with gedit, the file is something like this with the number of each row:
[image]
but in terminal it is shown without any row number:
[image]
So, it is difficult to distinguish among different rows.
How can I add the number of rows in my python script?

Comment: whats your problem? to find no of rows, or the memory is low to read file completely?

Comment: What have you tried and how did it fail? `fr` contains the text; count the number of lines in it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to show the number of the line, wrap the line iterator in `enumerate`, it will return a iterator of tuples with the index (zero based) and the line.

Like this:

```
with open('X1', 'r') as fr:
    for index, line in enumerate(fr):
        print(f'{index}: {line}')
```

Also, when working with files, using the context manager with `with` is better. It ensures proper closing and flushing the data buffers even if an exception is raised

---

EDIT:
As a bonus, the example I gave uses only iterators, the file object is a iterator of lines and `enumerate` also returns a iterator that builds the tuple.
This means that this script only holds only line at a time in memory (and the buffers defined by your platform), not the whole file.

Comment: If the OP just wants the total number of rows, you could print `index` after the for loop or create a `rnum` variable that increases each time through the loop.

Comment: OP said that his problem is distinguishing between different rows, but you are right, after the loop `index` will represent the index of the last row, add one and you have the number of rows

Answer (score 0):

```
fr = open('X1','r')
rowcount=0
for i in fr:
    print(rowcount,end="")
    print(":",end="")  
    print(i)
    rowcount+=1
print(rowcount)
fr.close()
```

---

We have just read file line by line and printing counter each time.